# Run scheduled tasks multiple times per day

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

Is there a way to run a scheduled task multiple times a day, instead of just one defined time, without creating multiple task jobs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create the task using "Create Task" instead of "Create Basic Task", you can specify for it to repeat with a smaller periodicity than one day. Every hour for instance.